# Encoding error reading CSV file (UNICODE encoded) C++

Tags: c++, csv, visual-c++, unicode, encoding

I need to read a csv (UNICODE) and put data in it in a 2d array now I've done it using strings but I need it using LPTSTR because the csv I have to process is UNICODE encoded and using string I can't read anything.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<vector<string> > values;
    vector<string> valueline;



    ifstream fin("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\test.csv");
    string item;
    for (string line; getline(fin, line); )
    {
        istringstream in(line);

        while (getline(in, item, ';'))
        {
            valueline.push_back(item.c_str());
        }

        values.push_back(valueline);
        valueline.clear();
    }

    fin.close();

    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < values[i].size(); j++){
            printf("%s;",values[i][j]);

}
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you sure your file is really unicode (like UTF-16) and has two bytes encoded characters, use "w" streams and strings (`std::wifstream` and `std::wstring`).

If your file could be in UTF-8 or any other encoding you should first perform conversion (so, read it as usual bytes stream first and then convert to `wstring`).

For converting from UTF-8 to wide strings (to `wstring`, which could be converted to unicode windows string) you can use `std::wstring_convert` and its member function `from_bytes` to convert your UTF-8 bytes into unicode characters:

```
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>, wchar_t> convert;
std::wstring myunicodestr = convert.from_bytes(myutf8str);
```

If you have to deal with other specific encodings you might need to utilize specific libraries for that, like `iconv`.

Comment: I tried it before your answer and worked thanks the same :D